# How to set Bootstrap navbar position fixed at top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am facing some issue with Bootstrap navbar. I am using Bootstrap v5.0.

- Whenever the bootstrap navbar expands, the contents below it is also going down. I don't want that. I want the content not to go down.
- I set the `position: fixed` but it didn't work and behaved abnormally. I want the `nav` to be fixed at the top.

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style: none;
        }
        header {
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(45, 44, 48, 0.753), rgba(45, 44, 48, 0.753)), url(./images/bg-masthead.jpg);
            height: 100vh;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        /* .navbar {
            position: fixed;
        } */
        #header-texts {
            height: 90vh;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #header-texts-1 {
            font-size: 55px;
        }
        #header-texts-2 {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #header-btn {
            background: #f24516;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            letter-spacing: 0.8px;
        }
        /* ========================= Responsive ========================= */
        @media (max-width: 540px) {
            #header-texts-1 {
                font-size: 30px;
            }
            #header-texts-2 {
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .container {
                width: 100vw !important;
            }
            .navbar-expand-lg {
                background: transparent !important;
            }
            a {
                color: white !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Creative</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                                <div class="navbar-nav" id="nav-items">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Protfolio</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center" id="header-texts">
                <div class="col">
                    <p id="header-texts-1">YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE<br>BOOTSTRAP THEMES</p>
                    <hr class="mb-4" style="width: 5%; margin: auto; height: 5px; border: none; color: #ff0000; background-color:#ff0000; opacity: 1;">
                    <p id="header-texts-2">Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap<br>framework! Just download a theme and start customizing, no strings attached!</p>
                    <button class="btn mt-4" id="header-btn">FIND OUT MORE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="sec-2">
        architecto similique rerum, laborum impedit pariatur repudiandae iusto ducimus soluta inventore quibusdam excepturi. Hic similique autem iure distinctio incidunt beatae cupiditate? Repudiandae, iusto eius quo cupiditate facere, dolore assumenda impedit iste ipsam distinctio magnam ad velit, dolor explicabo. Nihil adipisci eligendi dolorem est, voluptatem velit dicta illum amet delectus voluptatibus fuga nesciunt recusandae quaerat illo ipsum optio. Minus sequi excepturi nulla eligendi fuga, eius laborum dolorum maxime quo, optio ipsa eos, nostrum omnis illum voluptatum est! Repellendus facere tempora placeat illum hic nemo, nostrum omnis, numquam enim deleniti a, pariatur laboriosam fugiat dignissimos perspiciatis? Dignissimos excepturi eos nostrum provident, beatae libero ex tenetur, a repellendus soluta voluptas, delectus fugiat mollitia laboriosam veniam deserunt quas eaque! Magnam, minus id! Deleniti nemo nam, sint nihil alias similique vero maxime magnam iure! Temporibus odio aspernatur dignissimos hic rerum sed reiciendis, maxime minus adipisci ullam, aliquam veritatis, explicabo nobis reprehenderit iusto doloremque blanditiis esse ea. Facere harum ad ut commodi ipsum, explicabo excepturi. Suscipit expedita explicabo deleniti repellat! Quisquam est praesentium aspernatur excepturi, ipsum ullam vel sit ad esse pariatur asperiores, omnis incidunt minima similique eos quod sed. Veritatis laboriosam quod distinctio? Illum, ea iusto ad deserunt nihil deleniti voluptate ratione non neque cupiditate esse necessitatibus magnam! Tempora repellat, fugit explicabo delectus quos excepturi, aut nam incidunt eius voluptas non harum? Voluptate dolor aspernatur ut officiis laudantium odit odio nulla, temporibus incidunt alias commodi inventore error eligendi libero ea atque.
    </div>
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the header you can simply use

```
        .navbar {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

But in that case your main content will go beneath the header, to fix that add a top margin of YOUR_HEADER_HEIGHT to the main content, something like this

```
        #header-texts {
            margin-top: 60px; // your header height
            height: 90vh;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to you code. What I have done is wrapping your `nav` component in a `navbar-holder` class and adding necessary styles to the class which you can find in the code. Another suggestion from my side would be whenever you are going to scroll you should add another style to the navbar like adding a dark background because currently your navabr background is transparent and it would not look good when scrolled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
      }
      .navbar-holder {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .with-bg {
        background: #000000 !important;
      }
      header {
        background: linear-gradient(
            rgba(45, 44, 48, 0.753),
            rgba(45, 44, 48, 0.753)
          ),
          url(./images/bg-masthead.jpg);
        height: 100vh;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      /* .navbar {
            position: fixed;
        } */
      #header-texts {
        height: 90vh;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #header-texts-1 {
        font-size: 55px;
      }
      #header-texts-2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      #header-btn {
        background: #f24516;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 0.8px;
      }
      /* ========================= Responsive ========================= */
      @media (max-width: 540px) {
        #header-texts-1 {
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        #header-texts-2 {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .container {
          width: 100vw !important;
        }
        .navbar-expand-lg {
          background: transparent !important;
        }
        a {
          color: white !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <title>Creative</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="navbar-holder" id="navigation-holder">
        <nav
          class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
          id="navigation"
        >
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
              aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
              id="navbarNavAltMarkup"
            >
              <div class="navbar-nav" id="nav-items">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Protfolio</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center" id="header-texts">
          <div class="col">
            <p id="header-texts-1">
              YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE<br />BOOTSTRAP THEMES
            </p>
            <hr
              class="mb-4"
              style="
                width: 5%;
                margin: auto;
                height: 5px;
                border: none;
                color: #ff0000;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                opacity: 1;
              "
            />
            <p id="header-texts-2">
              Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the
              Bootstrap<br />framework! Just download a theme and start
              customizing, no strings attached!
            </p>
            <button class="btn mt-4" id="header-btn">FIND OUT MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="sec-2">
      architecto similique rerum, laborum impedit pariatur repudiandae iusto
      ducimus soluta inventore quibusdam excepturi. Hic similique autem iure
      distinctio incidunt beatae cupiditate? Repudiandae, iusto eius quo
      cupiditate facere, dolore assumenda impedit iste ipsam distinctio magnam
      ad velit, dolor explicabo. Nihil adipisci eligendi dolorem est, voluptatem
      velit dicta illum amet delectus voluptatibus fuga nesciunt recusandae
      quaerat illo ipsum optio. Minus sequi excepturi nulla eligendi fuga, eius
      laborum dolorum maxime quo, optio ipsa eos, nostrum omnis illum voluptatum
      est! Repellendus facere tempora placeat illum hic nemo, nostrum omnis,
      numquam enim deleniti a, pariatur laboriosam fugiat dignissimos
      perspiciatis? Dignissimos excepturi eos nostrum provident, beatae libero
      ex tenetur, a repellendus soluta voluptas, delectus fugiat mollitia
      laboriosam veniam deserunt quas eaque! Magnam, minus id! Deleniti nemo
      nam, sint nihil alias similique vero maxime magnam iure! Temporibus odio
      aspernatur dignissimos hic rerum sed reiciendis, maxime minus adipisci
      ullam, aliquam veritatis, explicabo nobis reprehenderit iusto doloremque
      blanditiis esse ea. Facere harum ad ut commodi ipsum, explicabo excepturi.
      Suscipit expedita explicabo deleniti repellat! Quisquam est praesentium
      aspernatur excepturi, ipsum ullam vel sit ad esse pariatur asperiores,
      omnis incidunt minima similique eos quod sed. Veritatis laboriosam quod
      distinctio? Illum, ea iusto ad deserunt nihil deleniti voluptate ratione
      non neque cupiditate esse necessitatibus magnam! Tempora repellat, fugit
      explicabo delectus quos excepturi, aut nam incidunt eius voluptas non
      harum? Voluptate dolor aspernatur ut officiis laudantium odit odio nulla,
      temporibus incidunt alias commodi inventore error eligendi libero ea
      atque.
    </div>
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        const { scrollTop } = document.documentElement;
        const nav = document.querySelector("#navigation-holder");
        if (scrollTop === 0) {
          nav.classList.remove("with-bg");
        } else {
          nav.classList.add("with-bg");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

How can I add another background color/style when scrolling for looking the navbar good? Is it possible by CSS or Bootstrap? Or I have use jQuery to change the navbar background color while scrolling?

Comment: What you need to do is add `scroll` eventlistener with javascript and whenever the `scrollTop` is greather than 0, add the class. I have edited my answer's code snippet. Please have a look at that.